# "failure starting java" when running Fortify 3.7.0

Tags: java, fortify

I am trying to run HP Fortify 3.7.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS version.  I don't think that it is officially supported, but I found this link indicating that another user got 3.8.0 to work, so I thought I would try: http://www.greebo.net/2013/02/28/running-fortify-sca-3-80-on-ubuntu-12-04-64-bit-linux/

The installation seemed to go fine.

I have Oracle Java 7.0.51 installed as my default Java.

When I run Audit Workbench, I get as far as selecting my project and staring the scan and get the error:

> SCA Commandline Invocation Failed failure starting java: No such file
>   or directory

When I run sourceanalyzer from the command line, I get:

> failure starting java: No such file or directory

I tried changing the path to java in the /opt/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_3.70/Core/private-bin/awb/productlaunch like the author of the blog mentioned above did but that did not solve the problem.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I switched jobs and no longer have access to HP Fortify, so I won't be able to verify an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command to run in 64 bit jre insted of renaming JRE dirs located under "HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_3.70"

sourceanalyzer **-64** **-Xmx8G** -b code -scan -f results.fpr

or you can you the following gradle task running ant task inside gradle task

[How to run HP fortify scan using gradle or Running Fortify from Gradle build on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473016/how-to-run-hp-fortify-scan-using-gradle-or-running-fortify-from-gradle-build-on)

( By default fortify runs in 32 bit mode which limits the java heap to 1200-1600 MB on windows and 3GB on modern linux machine and it uses jre directory to run 32 bit mode, if you want to run in 64 bit mode then you should pass sourceanalyzer -64 -Xmx8G option instead of changing jre name manually to switch run mode from 32 bit to 64 bit java)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

Inside the HP Fortify installation directory, rename the following folders:

- jre -> jre32
- jre64 -> jre

It helped me (on: Linux 3.11.0-12-generic x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

I am using RHEL7.

Problem:
I was getting failure starting java: No such file or directory

Solution:
I renamed JRE dirs located under "HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_3.70"

1. Rename jre -> jre32
2. Rename jre64 -> jre

Now, I am able to run now "sourceanalyzer -help"